# Pattern matching rewrites with internal DSL?

Tags: scala, haskell, pattern-matching, dsl

My question is about DSL design. It is related to internal vs. external DSLs, but is more specific than that. 
Background info: I have gone through [DSL in Action](http://www.manning.com/ghosh/) and other tutorials. The difference between internal and external is clear to me. I also have experience developing external DSLs in Haskell.

Let's take a very simple example. Here below a (simplified) relational algebra exression:

```
SELECT conditions (
  CROSS (A,B)
)
```

Algebra expressions ([ADT](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Algebraic_data_type) in Haskell) can be easily rewritten. For example, this can be trivially rewritten into:

```
JOIN conditions (A,B)
```

In the DSLs I have developed, I have always taken this approach: write a parser which creates algebraic expressions like the one above. Then, with a language that allows pattern matching like Haskell, apply a number of rewrites and eventually translate into a target language.

Here comes the question.

For a new DSL I would like to develop, I'd rather opt for an internal DSL. Mainly because I want to take advantage of the host language capabilities (probably Scala in this case). The debate of whether this is the right choice is not the point here. Let's assume its a good choice.

What I miss is: if I go for an internal DSL, then there is no parsing into an ADT. Where is my loved pattern matching rewrite going to fit into this? Do I have to give up on it? Are there best practices to get the best of the two worlds? Or am I not seeing things correctly here?

Comment: There are a couple of axes with DSLs - internal (embedded) vs external (standalone); and once you look at internal you have another axis shallow vs deep embedding. In an internal deep embedding you build abstract syntax of your intermediate language - so if you go for this option you can still have pattern matching rewrite rules.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll demonstrate this using an internal expression language for arithmetic in Haskell. We'll implement double-negation elimination.

Internal DSL "embeddings" are either deep or shallow. Shallow embeddings mean that you rely upon sharing operations from the host language to make the domain language run. In our example, this almost annihilates the very DSL-ness of our problem. I'll show it anyway.

```
newtype Shallow = Shallow { runShallow :: Int }

underShallow1 :: (Int -> Int) -> (Shallow -> Shallow)
underShallow1 f (Shallow a) = Shallow (f a)

underShallow2 :: (Int -> Int -> Int) -> (Shallow -> Shallow -> Shallow)
underShallow2 f (Shallow a) (Shallow b) = Shallow (f a b)

-- DSL definition
instance Num Shallow where
  fromInteger n = Shallow (fromInteger n)   -- embed constants

  (+) = underShallow2 (+)         -- lifting host impl into the DSL
  (*) = underShallow2 (*)
  (-) = underShallow2 (-)
  negate = underShallow negate
  abs    = underShallow abs
  signum = underShallow signum
```

So now we write and execute our `Shallow` DSL using the overloaded `Num` methods and `runShallow :: Shallow -> Int`

```
>>> fromShallow (2 + 2 :: Shallow)
4
```

Notably, since everything in this `Shallow` embedding is represented internally with almost no structure besides the result since all of the work has been dropped down to the host language where our domain language can't "see" it.

A deep embedding clearly separates the *representation* and the *interpretation* of a DSL. Typically, a good way to represent it is an ADT which has branches and arities which match a minimal, basis API. We'll just reflect the whole `Num` class

```
data Deep
  = FromInteger Integer
  | Plus Deep Deep
  | Mult Deep Deep
  | Subt Deep Deep
  | Negate Deep
  | Abs Deep
  | Signum Deep
deriving ( Eq, Show )
```

Notably, this representation will admit equality (note that this is the *smallest* equality possible since it ignores "values" and "equivalences") and showing, which is nice. We tie it into the same internal API by instantiating `Num`

```
instance Num Deep where
  fromInteger = FromInteger
  (+) = Plus
  (*) = Mult
  (-) = Subt
  negate = Negate
  abs    = Abs
  signum = Signum
```

but now we have to create an interpreter which ties the deep embedding into values represented in the host language. Here an advantage of `Deep` embeddings arises in that we can trivially introduce multiple interpreters. For instance, "showing" can be considered an interpreter from `Deep` to `String`

```
interpretString :: Deep -> String
interpretString = show
```

We can count the number of embedded constants as an interpreter

```
countConsts :: Deep -> Int
countConsts x = case x of
  FromInteger _ = 1
  Plus x y = countConsts x + countConsts y
  Mult x y = countConsts x + countConsts y
  Subt x y = countConsts x + countConsts y
  Negate x = countConsts x
  Abs x    = countConsts x
  Signum x = countConsts x
```

And finally we can interpret the thing into not just an `Int` but any other thing which follows the `Num` API

```
interp :: Num a => Deep -> a
interp x = case x of
  FromInteger n = fromInteger n
  Plus x y = interp x + interp y
  Mult x y = interp x * interp y
  Subt x y = interp x - interp y
  Negate x = negate (interp x)
  Abs x    = abs (interp x)
  Signum x = signum (interp x)
```

So, finally, we can create a deep embedding and execute it in several ways

```
>>> let x = 3 + 4 * 5 in (interpString x, countConsts x, interp x)
(Plus (FromInteger 3) (Mult (FromInteger 4) (FromInteger 5)), 3, 23)
```

And, here's the finale, we can use our `Deep` ADT to implement optimizations

```
opt :: Deep -> Deep
opt x = case x of
  (Negate (Negate x)) -> opt x
  FromInteger n = FromInteger n
  Plus x y = Plus (opt x) (opt y)
  Mult x y = Mult (opt x) (opt y)
  Subt x y = Sub (opt x) (opt y)
  Negate x = Negate (opt x)
  Abs x    = Abs (opt x)
  Signum x = Signum (opt x)
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this has made things clearer to me. I was under the impression that I was missing some more "magic", but it seems that compared to what I've been doing so far, I just need to replace the way the ADT is created. Not via a parser, but via the primitives of the designed domain language. Then rewrite and output as usual.

Comment: Yep, at least with deep embeddings. If your AST is a deep embedding you can think of the language API and the parser as two alternative "front-ends" for your AST. With a little care both will be admissible and work identically.